# how to Resize the video according the custom size in WinRT

Tags: video, windows-runtime, window-resize

I have a question on how to control the size of a MediaCapture video.  In the MediaCapture record, the video's default size appears to be the screen's size.

For example, when I set the CaptureElement's Width to 480, and the CaptureElement's Height to 320, I can see that the preview of the video's area is 480*320. But when I record it to a file and stop, the video's size in the file is the screen's size(the view area is 768*1280). How can I get the video's size in the file to be 320*240?

Primary code is:

```
            DeviceInformation cameraDevice = await FindDeviceInfo(panel);
            if (cameraDevice == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var mediaInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id };
            _encodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Qvga);
            if (_encodingProfile.Video != null)
            {
                _encodingProfile.Video.PixelAspectRatio.Numerator = 4;
                _encodingProfile.Video.PixelAspectRatio.Denominator = 3;
            }
            var isInitialized = false;
            try
            {
                _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.PrimaryUse = CaptureUse.Video;
                await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(mediaInitSettings);
                isInitialized = true;
                var formatSelector = new Func<VideoEncodingProperties, bool>(ep => ep.Height * ep.Width == 640 * 480 && string.Equals(ep.Subtype, "nv12", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                var recordFormat = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoRecord).OfType<VideoEncodingProperties>().FirstOrDefault(formatSelector);
                var previewFormat = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview).OfType<VideoEncodingProperties>().FirstOrDefault(formatSelector);
                if (previewFormat != null)
                    await
                        _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview,
                            previewFormat);
                if (recordFormat != null)
                    await
                        _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoRecord,
                            recordFormat);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception when initializing MediaCapture with {0}: {1}", cameraDevice.Id, ex.ToString());
            }
```

I tried to use MediaComposition, but there is no information about the Resize method that would help me solve the problem. How can I solve it?

Link to an image of the preview is[1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dnIi.png   the result can see more region.

Comment: I edited grammar and paragraph formatting to make the post a little easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation that should cover what you're trying to do:

1. [CameraStarterKit](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit)
2. [CameraResolution](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraResolution)
3. [Set media encoding properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt592658.aspx)

The first sample will show you a basic camera app, with a simple way to initialize it, and record video.

The second one will teach you how to choose at what resolution you want to capture video. The size of the CaptureElement is unrelated to the size of the preview frames, as it can do scaling for you.

If you want to change the video resolution, the documentation at the third link should explain most of the things you need to know.

By using VideoEncodingQuality.Qvga, you're setting the pipeline up for transcoding. This means that the camera device will capture video at its default resolution, and Windows will then resize it to fit QVGA dimensions. This can cause a loss of quality, so it's generally recommended to use VideoEncodingQuality.Auto instead, and use `SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync` to choose the video capture resolution at the source, provided the camera supports your desired dimensions.

Finally, that last documentation link also mentions an important aspect:

> On some devices, the same hardware pin is used for both preview and
>   capture streams. On these devices, setting the encoding properties of
>   one will also set the other. On devices that use different hardware
>   pins for capture and preview, the properties can be set for each
>   stream independently. Use the following code to determine if the
>   preview and capture streams are independent. You should adjust your UI
>   to enable or disable the setting of the streams independently based on
>   the result of this test.

Comment: hi,I am happy to receive your answer. I have saw the sample. The question is not Resolution,  it's Resize. I want to get the result is a half of the screen, but the camera's result is a full of screen. Likely, the ffmpeg's crop command. Is there some api for it? Thanks!